# Highcharts - stop Y axis value change on redraw

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When the graph redraws (zoom or resize), the Y axis values change (the max value changes) leaving a big white gap on the top of the graph (no data).

Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1vrvn2q/8/) of the problem (with both real and fake data, same result) and some [pictures of my actual graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YIx9.jpg).

These are my options for that chart :

```
var chartOptions = {
    title: false,

    xAxis: {
        lineWidth: 0,
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    yAxis: [{
        lineWidth: 0,
    },
    {
        lineWidth: 0,
        opposite: true,     
    }],

    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        yAxis: 0,
        type : "area",
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        yAxis: 1,
        type : "area",
    },
    {
        name: 'C',
        type : "spline",
        yAxis: 0,
    }],

    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            threshold: null
        },
    },

    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',

    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
};
```

Comment: You can set alignTicks as false. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b1vrvn2q/9/

Comment: Wow @SebastianBochan this is exactly what I looking for ! Thanks a bunch ! Please consider replying and I'll accept your answer as it's spot on in my case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set alignTicks as false. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/b1vrvn2q/9

```
chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        alignTicks:false
    },
```